# Can i use the if/else if command in an html document

Tags: javascript, html

I need to use the if command for js in a html document but it won't work. I have tried several different similar commands but nothing worked.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you are trying to do and include an example of what you have tried.

Comment: "if command"? HTML has no notion of conditional logic.

Comment: I've got lots of ideas, but most of them are about cats :). Please read about [ask] questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but here are answers - HTML has nothing like if/else statements, but javascript does.

So if you are asking about javascript in html source - of course you can.
It will looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

   HTML part

  <script>
   var x = 5;
   var y = 3;

   if ( x > y ) 
   {
      console.log('true');
   } 
   else 
   {
      console.log('false');
   }
  </script> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: bad thing not using separate js file but question is a real pain to understand

Comment: @aviel Seperating out the code in a simple example like this likely would hurt readability.